# Deleting (dangling) forwarding-rules in gcloud

Tags: gcloud

We have a script that spawns clusters ip addresses and adds dns records for test environment in google cloud using `gcloud container cluster create ..` etc.

Then we will kubernetes and add a loadbalancer in front of the proxy.

Also there is a script that then deletes cluster again later, and ip and dns records.

Now i just released this month my payment was double as usual and after some research i found out i paid a big amount for `Network Load Balancing: Forwarding Rule Additional Service Charge`.

I went to the `Networking > Load Balancing > Forwarding rules` and here i see tons of forwarding rules forwarding to clusters that not even exist anymore. but these forwarding rules (that I never explicitly created, only indirectly through kubectl is suppose) are now still here.

The problem is i also have some which are actually in use and should not be removed. is there any way I Can filter on dangling forwarding rules i tried it but i couldn't find a way to manually do this.

I tried:

- `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list`
- `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --filter=dangling` #returns nothing
- `gcloud compute target-pools list`

Answer (score 0):

To make sure gcloud no longer lets us pay for things they forget to delete i made a simple node script that removes dangling artifacts from the compute part of gcloud:

I'm not sure if its watertight because i shortcut forwarding-rules and target-pools references.

missing parts in this script (you'd have to implement):

- `const Promise = require('bluebird')`
- Extension method `lastItem()` on Array.prototype
- `cmd.executeDirect()` => child_process.execFile() in a Promise.

script:

```
/**
 * Remove left over compute items indirectly created by kubernetes but not removed automatically
 */
deleteDanglingComputeItems() {
    return this.getComputeInstances()
        .then(instances => {
            var dict = {};
            instances.forEach(x => dict[x.name] = true);
            var killPoolsPromise = this.getComputeTargetpools()
                .filter(pool => !pool.instances.some(inst => dict[inst.split("/").lastItem()] === true))
                .then(pools => {
                    var poolDict = {};
                    pools.forEach(x => poolDict[x.name] = true)

                    return this.getComputeForwardingRules()
                        .filter(rules => poolDict[rules.target.split('/').lastItem()] === true)
                        .map(rule => this.deleteComputeForwardingRule(rule.name, rule.region))
                        .then(() => pools);
                })
                .map(pool => this.deleteComputeTargetpool(pool.name, pool.region))


            var firewallPromise = this.getComputeFirewallRules()
                .filter(rule => rule.targetTags && !rule.targetTags.some(target => dict[target] === true))
                .then(rules => this.deleteFirewallRules(rules.map(x=> x.name)))
            //Todo add firewall
            return Promise.all([killPoolsPromise, firewallPromise]);
        });
}


getComputeInstances() {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'instances', 'list']);
}

getComputeTargetpools() {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'target-pools', 'list'])
}

getComputeForwardingRules() {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'forwarding-rules', 'list'])
}

getComputeFirewallRules() {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'firewall-rules', 'list'])
}


deleteComputeTargetpool(pool, region) {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'target-pools', 'delete', pool, '--region', region])
}

deleteComputeTargetpools(pools = []) {
    if (pools.length === 0)
        return Promise.resolve();
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'target-pools', 'delete', ...pools])
}

deleteComputeForwardingRule(rule, region) {
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'forwarding-rules', 'delete', rule, '--region', region])
}

deleteFirewallRules(rules = []) {
    if (rules.length === 0)
        return Promise.resolve();
    return this._execJson(['compute', 'firewall-rules', 'delete', ...rules])
}

/**
 * @param {string[]} parameters
 * @param {ExecFileOptions} options
 */
_exec(parameters, options) {
    return cmd.get('gcloud', parameters, options);
}

/**
 * @returns {Promise} with result data.
 */
_execJson(parameters, optionFlags = {}, cmdOptions) {
    return this._exec(parameters.concat(this._generateFlags(optionFlags)), cmdOptions)
        .promise
        .tap(c => { log.debug(c.stderr); log.debug(c.stdout); })
        .then(x => JSON.parse(x.stdout));
}
```